# Ionic Cordova Application not working in some devices

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, phonegap

I am facing some issue with my application. It stops working in some devices only. Here is Android studio LogCat. This happens with only selected devices, on other phones its working fine.

```
    2019-01-14 12:40:03.065 31254-31346/? I/GoogleConversionReporter: Pinging: https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/1001694263/?bundleid=com.vsdirect.android&appversion=2.6.2&osversion=8.0.0&sdkversion=ct-sdk-a-v2.2.4&gms=1&lat=0&rdid=e41424eb-5ca8-444c-8011-0d1344099e76&timestamp=1547458.801&auto=1&usage_tracking_enabled=1
2019-01-14 12:40:03.072 31384-31409/? D/StrictMode: StrictMode policy violation: android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeDiskReadViolation: policy=65599 violation=2
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onReadFromDisk(StrictMode.java:1438)
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.checkAccess(UnixFileSystem.java:251)
        at java.io.File.exists(File.java:807)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.ensurePrivateDirExists(ContextImpl.java:565)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.ensurePrivateDirExists(ContextImpl.java:556)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.getPreferencesDir(ContextImpl.java:512)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.getSharedPreferencesPath(ContextImpl.java:704)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.getSharedPreferences(ContextImpl.java:372)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:178)
        at com.google.android.finsky.ah.f.a(SourceFile:4)
        at com.google.android.finsky.ah.q.a(SourceFile:5)
        at com.google.android.finsky.analytics.al.a(SourceFile:32)
        at com.google.android.finsky.application.impl.c.a(SourceFile:92)
        at com.google.android.finsky.application.impl.c.br(SourceFile:88)
        at com.google.android.finsky.application.impl.bo.a_(SourceFile:7)
        at b.b.a.f.a(SourceFile:11)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.s.a(SourceFile:5)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.r.run(SourceFile:17)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.bn.run(SourceFile:3)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.a.f.a.i.run(SourceFile:7)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at com.google.android.finsky.bn.w.run(Unknown Source:5)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2019-01-14 12:40:03.077 4938-6773/? D/ConnectivityService: filterNetworkStateForUid() uid: 10443 networkInfo: [type: WIFI[] - WIFI, state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: "Acumen", failover: false, available: true, roaming: false, metered: false]
2019-01-14 12:40:03.085 31384-31409/? D/StrictMode: StrictMode policy violation: android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeDiskReadViolation: policy=65599 violation=2
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onReadFromDisk(StrictMode.java:1438)
        at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.awaitLoadedLocked(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:233)
        at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.contains(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:300)
        at com.google.android.finsky.ah.k.a(SourceFile:5)
        at com.google.android.finsky.ah.q.a(SourceFile:5)
        at com.google.android.finsky.analytics.al.a(SourceFile:32)
        at com.google.android.finsky.application.impl.c.a(SourceFile:92)
        at com.google.android.finsky.application.impl.c.br(SourceFile:88)
        at com.google.android.finsky.application.impl.bo.a_(SourceFile:7)
        at b.b.a.f.a(SourceFile:11)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.s.a(SourceFile:5)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.r.run(SourceFile:17)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.bn.run(SourceFile:3)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.a.f.a.i.run(SourceFile:7)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at com.google.android.finsky.bn.w.run(Unknown Source:5)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Appreciate any possible help

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using any cordova plugin??
what permission access is made before execting the app?

Comment: same problem!  Some cordova apis simply do not support some versions of Android, and some Android phones have internal security policy (set by manufacturer) that remove some permission of newly installed non-famous apps(most of them are mobile phones made in China), users have to go to phone settings and set permissions.